# how to make a graduated line on photoshop? (CS6)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What's the easiest way to build a graduated line (eg. the one on a ruller)?

(I found this [thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/427208) talking about it, but I did not manage to "format the stroke")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the most flexible way to do it would be to use the type tool.

You can do it using many other methods, but if you use the type tool and just copy&pase the character:`|` multiple times, you can easily adjust the spacing, width, height and color from the `Window > Character` panel.

[image]

Comment: Ah dear... You were faster than me!  Good to know I'm not the only one with barbaric methods^^

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, barbaric ways are the fastest and easiest.
My awful method would be to use the Text tool and to repeat Pipe symbol |

[image]

Comment: Excellent! It completes Joonas's answer

Answer (score 2):

(As mayersdesign has mentioned this would be much easier in Illustrator... but if Photoshop is all you have – it can still be done, and in vector format as well...)

If you need the gradations to be accurate (as in lines which are *precisely* a certain number of pixels apart) then I would use the Line Tool:

[image: Line Tool]

Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, click and drag to draw a line, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, go to the top of the UI and line it up to an easy whole number like 100px:

[image: Exact Positioning]

And now some math: For the sake of simplicity say I want a rule which is 2000px in length and which has a line every 25px... 2000/25 = 80 sections, so I want 81 lines in total (one line sits at the zero point).

So I duplicate my line by having its layer active in the Layers Panel and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. I would do this 10 times to give me 11 lines, then I would select the top 10 lines and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> 7 more times to give me 81 lines:

[image: 81 layers]

Now I will highlight my 81st (last) line in the layers panel and using the Move Tool (<kbd>V</kbd> key) while holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, drag it exactly 2000px to the right. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> again and at the top of the UI again make sure it sits at exactly the 2,000px position.

Then select all layers and go to 'Distribute horizontal centers':

[image: Alignment buttons]

And that gives us this result, with a line precisely every 25px:

[image: 81 Lines]

If you want to get fancy, you can select all of your layers and then use the Direct Selection Tool (<kbd>A</kbd> key: white arrow) to alter the line lengths at the ¼ and ½ points to come up with this look:

[image: Hey that looks like a ruler]

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you tried to follow was for InDesign, but here's one way to do it in Photoshop:

1. Open a document with (say) 5x5 pixels
2. Zoom in and select a row on the left and colour them black
3. Hit "edit" > "define pattern" and call it (say) "5x5 Bar" (you can experiment with different amounts of white space, and different thickness lines)
4. Select an area in a new document and hit "edit" > "fill" > select you pattern and hit ok.

PS - I imagine this is a LOT easier and has more options in Illustrator by the way.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Guillaume No problem, hope that helped you out